# Walk and set value to complex Javascript object

Tags: javascript

I note the following similarity to this post:
[Dynamic deep setting for a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842795/dynamic-deep-setting-for-a-javascript-object)

However, the above post is based upon a known structure and depth to the javascript object and not truly dynamic.  Truly dynamic would suggest that you did not have any precursor knowledge of the structure, just a path and a value to replace it with.  I have created a fairly good use case over on JSFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/kstubs/nJrLp/1/

```
function Message(message) {
$('result').insert('<div>' + message + '</div>');
}

var obj = {
"array": [1, 2, 3],
"boolean": true,
"null": null,
"number": 123,
"object": {
    "a": "b",
    "c": "d",
    "e": "f",
    "complex_array1": [{
        "g": "h"
    }, {
        "bingo": "bongo"
    }, {
        "x": {
            "complex_array2": [{
                "h": "i"
            }, {
                "j": "k"
            }, {
                "bingo": "bongo"
            }, {
                "bango": "jango"
            }]
        }
    }]
},
"string": "Hello World"
};

var list = [{
"h": "i"
}, {
"j": "k"
}];

function walk(path,value) {
var a = path.split('.');
var context = obj;

for (i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    context = context[a[i]];
}
```

}

The use case:

1. Find complex_array2
2. Update its list to a new list (a new array)

The new array is the array list which should replace the list for complex_array2.  The javascript function *walk* does just that, walks the javascript object until the path criteria is met and then sets the value to whatever value is passed to the walk function, however the new value does not stick.

I know why it doesn't stick, because as you walk over an object of type array you lose the pointer to the original object.  So, the challenge is to **walk** the javascript object and not lose context of the original object.

Thanks for any assistance.

Karl..

Comment: So....what's the question? Do you really need it or you just want to challenge SO users? What have you tried?

Comment: var context = obj, old=obj;  ...   old[a[i]]="whatever"

Comment: This could be of interest -- one of my own answers to a slightly different flavour of question -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163160/searching-json-object-key-containing-value-then-unset-it/12170015#12170015

Comment: Yes @AurelioDeRosa it is really needed.  I have a complex javascript object which is dynamically bound to a web form.  The object is stored in a text field as a Json string.

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over all but the last element in the path.  Then the final element is used for assignment after the loop.

```
var i = 0;

for (; i < a.size() - 1; i++) {
    context = context[a[i]];
}

context[a[i]] = value;
```

Technically you can leave the declaration of `i` inside the `for`.  I just find this clearer.

http://jsfiddle.net/nJrLp/2/

Comment: Exactly!  I came up with the same answer: http://jsfiddle.net/kstubs/nJrLp/3/  based on Andrew's remarks.

Comment: It's unrelated to this, but the way you are using `i` without declaring it first with `var` makes it a global variable.  You really shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code doesn't work as it's written is because rather than changing a property on an object you have a reference to, you're actually changing which object your local variable points to.

```
context = context[a[i]];
```

`context` is a pointer to an object, and it's a local variable. When you assign to it, you're assigning a new pointer value, which loses the reference to the previous object. If you want to replace it, you'll have to refer to it from its parent object. Assume `parent` is one such object; once you locate your target object's key name (let's say you've put it in variable `key`), you could overwrite the existing value as such:

```
parent[key] = new_value;
```

This will dereference `parent`, find the property named by `key`, and replace its value (which is a pointer) with the memory address of `new_value`. What you have currently works something like this:

```
var context = parent[key];
context = new_value;
```

In this case you're simply changing the pointer value of the local variable `context`, not the object that `parent[key]` points to.

Comment: Like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/kstubs/nJrLp/3/  
Its seem this is working, which is fantastic.  Plugging this into the real solution and will report any other issues I may find.

Answer (score 0):

I used a helper function for reading complex json objects. (http://jsfiddle.net/JBBAJ/)

```
var object = {
    data: {
        users: [
            {
                firstName: "White"
            },
            {
                firstName: "Black"
            }
        ]
    }
}
var read = function(path, obj) {
    var path = path.split(".");
    var item = path.shift();
    if(item.indexOf("]") == item.length-1) {
        // array
        item = item.split("[");
        var arrayName = item.shift();
        var arrayIndex = parseInt(item.shift().replace("]", ""));
        var arr = obj[arrayName || ""];
        if(arr && arr[arrayIndex]) {
            return read(path.join("."), arr[arrayIndex]);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        // object
        if(obj[item]) {
            if(path.length === 0) {
                return obj[item];
            } else {
                return read(path.join("."), obj[item]);
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
console.log(read("data.users[0].firstName", object)); // White
console.log(read("data.users[1].firstName", object)); // Black
console.log(read("data.test.users[0]", object)); // null
```

The function *read* accepts a path and an object.